# Converting PDF to html with PDFminer

Tags: python

I am trying to use the pdfminer command line tool to convert a pdf file to an html file, after running this

```
pdf2txt.py -o output.html -t html casino.pdf
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pdf2txt.py", line 101, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/local/bin/pdf2txt.py", line 87, in main
    layoutmode=layoutmode, laparams=laparams, outdir=outdir)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'outdir'
```

I have used this library before and it was working perfectly, I am really having a hard time to understand whats going on

here is a link to the library http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html

Answer (score 2):

it seems to be working after deleting and re-installing the library

Answer (score 2):

in file /usr/local/bin/pdf2txt.py on line 98 remove `, debug=debug` and it will work. I am not sure why the code author insert this arg where it is erroneous.